# Eclipse does not see my device from one day to another (samsung galaxy s3 mini)

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, usb

Okay so the **facts:**

I have been **developing for Android device (Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini GT-I8190) in my PC for the last half year.**

When i installed the developing tools, android SDK, eclipse, etc, **all was like "plug and play"**
It was easy **and worked verry well.**

So some days ago i just realised Eclipse **shows my device NO MORE**, here is how i tried to solve this issue in chronologic sorting:

- Tried to replug my device
- Tried to restart eclipse
- Tried to restart device
- Tried to restart PC
- Tried to uninstall USB drivers and reinstall via Kies (I have tried
  the old Kies, it has installed a driver which was not worked.)
- I tried to update my Kies to a newer version and install the usb
  driver    again, not helped.
- I tried with the new Kies 3, and it says    that this    version does
  not recognise my device.
- I tried to uninstall Kies, uninstall the the usb driver and download
  a simple SAMSUNG driver file, so basicly i tried to install it
  without Kies, not helped.
- I tried to reinstall Windows 8.1 (yes, i made a whole system reinstall for this, which is not helped)
- I tried to download Google usb drivers from SDK manager, not helped
- I tried some commands to adb like "kill server" "starts server"
- I tried to manually update driver from MyComputer's manage menu, not
  helped.
- I have made a factory reset on my device.

My computer sees my device so i can trasfer files. Developer mode is on.

Running `adb devices` output is empty, so i cannot see my device in list.

**So here i am at a projects deadline with a mystery and i cant get it work.**

Whoever solves this **gets 500 reputation from me.** Im not kidding, this is all i can offer.

**E D I T:**

Tried everything mentioned below. Is it possible that my phone or my PC's hardware makes this mess?

Comment: For one I respect Ubuntu!

Comment: Change the usb cable.

Comment: I can transer files, so the cable is OK.

Comment: Re-enabled developer options after reset?

Comment: check the device manager..sometimes..it doesnt recognizes your device as ADB..also..reset your ADB once..if you see some hardware which is not recognized..please install it

Comment: Have you installed google usb-drivers from your sdk folder? If not, please use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is mindf. itself.

Today i asked my friend to test this problem with his device, (he's got a very same galaxy s3 mini device) and what i found was really blown my mind.

Eclipse does see his device, but not mine.

**

### Yes, two identical, very same product and mine is invisible for Eclipse.

**

I just cant find words...

Answer (score 0):

As you hav tried every method now try [Universal Naked Driver 0.72](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1161769) removing previously installed drivers.

Universal Naked Driver works for most of the devices.
another alternative [UniversalAdbDriver](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH)

Comment: Both of these said when i want to update the driver:
The choosen folder does not contains compatible driver for this device. Please make sure the driver you choosen is for Windows x64 system

(The error message is translated from hungarion to english so it may be differ from the original english error message.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Right click on My Computer --> Properties --> Device Manager --> Right Click on your device --> Update driver software --> Click on " Browse my computer for driver software --> Give path of your android sdk like "D:\Android_Sdk\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver" and tick "Include subfolders" --> Click next

Now repeat the steps till "Browse my computer for driver software".
Then click on "Let me pick form list of device drivers on my computer -> Click on the first option and click next and then click yes.
Drivers will be installed for your device.

This works for me.Hope this helps.

Comment: And now my device have disappeared from device manager, i will go mad now.

Comment: Please try with different usb cable bro. It will surely work.I had this problem earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this process :-

1.Uninstall previously installed drivers and close eclipse

2.Connect your device with USB storage & USB debugging in Developers options on

3.Go to find new hardware wizard in you computer

4.Install Drivers including adb from there by selecting your device

5.After that restart eclipse , your device might be detected

These steps worked for me when i faced the same problem but my device was different , hope this works for you

Comment: What do you mean by Install Drivers including adb ?

Answer (score 0):

Also check your supply USB port too, if u pass on a hub usb disconnect of this and link to pc directly.

Answer (score 0):

follow this:
1 . find in SDK Manager --> Extra --> Google USB Driver -->install.

2 . please install samsung kies3 in your system . and connect your device with it         then   try ..it will work 100% . also tell me which target version you r using in your project if it 19 API level and your mobile is 17-18 API level then it ADT will not give u permission to run (not show you your device in  android device choose dialog )

Comment: It is installed. And Kies3 says my device is not compatible with Kies3

Comment: then please find 2 solution in which api level u r working ??? and also find your mobile api level .

Comment: instead of kies3 u can use kies .. may be it will support your mobile . http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Answer (score 0):

(It happened to me today after the updating from 22.3 to 22.6)

Verify " **AndroidManifest.xml > Manifest Extras > Uses sdk > Min SDK Version** " suits your device.

I was using my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini GT-I8190L and **I forgot that the minimum SDK for mine is API 16 (for Android v4.1.2).** I fixed the number and now everything it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [UniversalAdbDriver](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver). It worked perfectly for me (GT-I8190).